# enabling a div when hovering over a certain object

Tags: css

Hej, I want to enable (modify opacity) a div, when hovering over a certain object.

```
#css_menu > .menu > .current:hover{
    background-color:#066;}
```

This works.

```
#css_menu:hover + .css_submenu {
    background-color:#F63;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This works. However.

```
#css_menu > .menu > .current:hover + .css_submenu{
    background-color:#F63;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This does not work and i wonder why.

The html in question looks like this:

```
<div class="css_menu" id="css_menu">
<ul class="menu">
<li id="item-122" class="current active"><a href="/index.php/de/" ><span>Galerie</span></a></li><li id="item-133"><a href="/index.php/de/menue-2" ><span>Menü</span></a></li></ul></div>
<div class="css_submenu" id="css_submenu">....</div>
```

The "menu" code is automatically generated from Joomla. Is there a CSS way to have the submenu only visible, when i hover over the current/active menu element?

Thanx for any insight.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No, that is not possible using this structure - because the submenu is not a _sibling_ of the list item. (And before you ask - [no, there is no parent selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1427878) …)

Answer (score 3):

The `+` selector is looking for an element that isnt there.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

> The + combinator selects **adjacent siblings**. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent.

For it to work you would need to put `css-submenu` inside `ul` as a `li` and right after `current`:

```css
#css_menu>.menu>.current:hover+.css_submenu {
  background-color: #F63;
  max-height: 100px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition-duration: .7s;
}

.css_submenu {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_menu" id="css_menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="item-122" class="current active">
      <a href="/index.php/de/"><span>Galerie</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="css_submenu" id="css_submenu">This will now have the hover effect</li>
    <li id="item-133"><a href="/index.php/de/menue-2"><span>Menü</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will work for you :)

```css
div {
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
}
    
a:hover + div {
    opacity:.1
}
```

```html
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div>Change opacity on hover</div>
```